# How do I link my conditional modifier to a selected value?

Tags: swift, swiftui, conditional-statements, modifier

I'm currently working through Hacking with Swift, 100 days of Swift and I'm a little stuck with the following issue.

I'm trying to use a conditional modifier to change foreground color depending on if the user selected tip is 0%, but after several hours I'm struggling in trying to change the @State from false to true if tip selected is 0%.

I think it might be an understanding issue as, I've been trying if statements that produce an error that doesn't conform to the view, so I wonder if this is where view modifiers/custom views should be used instead and perhaps I've just not understood this as part of the course material.

My code below:

```
import SwiftUI


struct ContentView: View {

@State private var restaurantBill = ""
@State private var diners = 2
@State private var selectedTip = 2

let tipAmount = [5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 0]

@State private var noTipSelected = false // <-- no tip selected state is equal to false

// computed properties
var totalPerPerson: Double {
    let peopleToCount = Double(diners + 2)
    let tipSelection = Double(tipAmount[selectedTip])
    let orderAmount = Double(restaurantBill) ?? 0
    
    let tipValue = orderAmount / 100 * tipSelection
    let grandTotal = tipValue + orderAmount
    let costPerPerson = grandTotal / peopleToCount
    
    return costPerPerson
}

var totalOverall: Double {
    let tipSelection = Double(tipAmount[selectedTip])
    let orderAmount = Double(restaurantBill) ?? 0
    
    let tipValue = orderAmount / 100 * tipSelection
    let grandTotal = tipValue + orderAmount
    
    return grandTotal
}



    
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        Form {
            Section {
                TextField("£ total bill amount", text: $restaurantBill)
                    .keyboardType(.numberPad)
            }
            
            Picker("Table for: ", selection: $diners){
                ForEach(2..<100){
                    Text("\($0) diners")
                }
            }
            
            Picker("Select Tip: ", selection: $selectedTip){
                ForEach(0..<tipAmount.count){
                    Text("\(self.tipAmount[$0])%")
                }
            }
            .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
            
            
            Section {
                Text("Total bill is: £\(totalOverall, specifier: "%.2f")")
                    .foregroundColor(noTipSelected ? .green : .red) //<---- my conditional modifier
            }
            
            
            Section {
                Text("Each diner pays: £\(totalPerPerson, specifier: "%.2f")")
                    
                    
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("WeSplit v2.0")
    }
}
```

}

```
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: Where you do attempt to change `noTipSelected`? Also you could alternatively use `.foregroundColor(tipAmount == 5 ? .green : .red)`.

Comment: I agree, you don't need a separate @State variable for this, you can use `selectedTip` for this (which I think is what George really meant in his comment and not tipAmount)

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Yep you are right I did mean `selectedTip` - or even more obvious of intensions, `tipAmount[selectedTip] == 0`. Also better in case `tipAmount` is adjusted in the future.

Comment: thanks to all, I've made this change `(tipAmount[selectedTip] == 0 ? .red : .green)` which works great. It also looks like I've made an error in assuming that that @State property was required when it's not! Which explains why I've been going around in circles.